# Pandas: Group sums of n consecutive elemens in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

Let `df` be a pandas dataframe of the following form:

```
n   days 
1    9.0
2    4.0
3    5.0 
4    1.0 
5    4.0    
6    1.0
7    7.0
8    3.0
```

For given `N`, and every row `i>=N` I want to sum the values in`df.days.iloc[i-N+1:i+1]`, and write them into a new column, in row `i`. 
The result should look like this (e.g., for `N = 3`):

```
n   days loc_sum
1    9.0     NaN
2    4.0     NaN
3    5.0    18.0
4    1.0    10.0
5    4.0    10.0
6    1.0     6.0
7    7.0    12.0
8    3.0    11.0
```

Of course, I could simply loop through all `i`, and insert `df.days.iloc[i-N+1:i+1].sum()` for every `i`.

My question is: Is there a more elegant way, using `pandas` functionality? Especially for large datasets, looping through the rows seems to be a very slow option.

Comment: df.rolling(3).sum()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rolling` with a windows equal to 3 and function `sum`:

```
df['loc_sum'] = df['days'].rolling(3).sum()
```

Output:

```
   n  days  loc_sum
0  1   9.0      NaN
1  2   4.0      NaN
2  3   5.0     18.0
3  4   1.0     10.0
4  5   4.0     10.0
5  6   1.0      6.0
6  7   7.0     12.0
7  8   3.0     11.0
```